# Append data to html page from CS in windows form

Tags: html, database, winforms

It's a Windows based application.

I'm completely clueless, I have searched the web but was not able to find appropriate answer.

I'm fetching data from Database say field1,field2 and fields3 in class GetResult. And in my project I am having HTML Template created with 3 labels

What I am suppose to do is I have to append this(field1,field2 and fields3) values to labels in HTML.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Two ways that I can think of-

1. Regular expressions - Use regexes to find the labels in your html
   template and replace them with values of field1, 2 and 3.
2. Use a Html parsing library like [htmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) which provides DOM manipulation in C#. There are quite a few examples on their codePlex site.

Using a Html parsing library is generally better than regexes, as regexes tend to fail lot more easily (or rather its hard to take care of all the edge conditions in regex).